# FrameLayout child moves automatically

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a layout whose parent is FrameLayout with 2 children. First child is a ListView and second child is also ListView. Second Child covers the first one as everybody knows. I move the second child programatically to show part first child. At the same time I update listview (need to update listview when it is being seen) second child moves automatically to its defaultposition (top left corner-0,0).

Actually, the second child should be there itself where I have moved and should not come to default position. And, to change the listview contents I am setting the adapter (I used notifyDataSetChanged too but same results).

Does anybody know how to make second child not to move???

Here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ms_complete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/message_background" >


<!-- first child -->
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ListView>


<!-- second child -->


<ListView
                android:id="@+id/msgs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/message_background"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hod do you move the second `ListView`?

Comment: Through animation (Translate Animation).

Comment: anybody knows?? Actually, what I came to know is "I am redrawing first child of Framelayout so all other children are moved to default position [0,0]". Any solution to make children not to move???

Comment: Use an AnimationListener and when the animation finishes modify the margin of the ListView to the correct value.

Comment: I have modified the margin too, second child moves when I redraw first child.